# I'm replacing some coworkers' old (Win XP) PCs with new ones (Win 7). They only login via the network domain. Will all files/settings transfer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-server-2003, domain

So, four coworkers of mine are getting new Windows 7-installed machines to replace their ancient Windows XP ones. All of these users login to the (Windows Server 2003) domain for mail and files, etc., not to the local. I need to make sure that they have all the files, emails, and settings they need to be up and running when I replace their current PCs.

I've Googled relentlessly but can't find answers to simple questions:

- Do I need to use something like Windows Easy Transfer since they work via the domain and not on the local? I'm not sure if everything is saved automatically on the server, or if some necessary files are only stored locally.
- Will logging back into the domain on the new Windows 7 machines result in each user's files/settings being repopulated automatically? E.g., My Documents.
- We use a mail server and Outlook for email purposes. I know that emails are saved on the server -- is getting a user access to their email as simple as setting up Outlook with the server?

I know these are multiple questions... I really appreciate any help.

Comment: I would still use the Transfer Wizard, but the one on the Windows 7 disc. You will still be able to restore the files to the network user, provided you've logged into the Windows 7 machine with the network credentials to create the account locally.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. What is the Transfer Wizard transferring that isn't automatically retrievable?

Comment: Profile settings that pertain to the local machine, local registry settings, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use the Windows Easy Tranfer wizard from the Windows 7 DVD, or download a new one online (Google "Windows Easy Transfer from Windows XP")
- Depends on the server setup. With Roaming Profiles, yes, settings/documents will re-appear automatically. With Local Profiles, no they will not
- Yes it is

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm curious as to what the WET wizard would do if the settings/documents will reappear on their own?

Comment: Not 100% sure what it would do, as I've ever only ran it on NEW Windows 7 installs

Comment: @MrT Also, if this is the answer you're looking for (or it solves your question), feel free to mark it as the answer by clicking the shaded check mark next to my answer